# Insert Hibernate model using Spring EntityManager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, hql

I have this Hibernate table which I would like populate with data and save into database.

```
public class Terminals implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String mode;

    @Column
    private boolean remote_test;

    .....
}
```

I'm using Spring datasource with EntityManager in order to select data.
How I can use getters/setters to populate the model and save it without using native HQL query?

```
Terminals obj = new Terminal();
obj.set....
```

How I can insert the model?

Comment: https://spring.io/blog/2011/02/10/getting-started-with-spring-data-jpa/ is a good starting point; in service layer you construct your object; after passing it to your repository you use the methods of the injected entity manager to save your entity

Comment: but this tutorial uses JPA. I want to use Hibernate

Comment: Hibernate in an implementation of JPA, so transition should be simple and without side-effects. With little costs.

Comment: if you are using EntityManager, you are using JPA
since JPA is sort of an interface, you still need to provide the implementation which can be Hibernate
e.g. https://www.boraji.com/spring-4-hibernate-5-jpa-2-integration-example
if you want pure Hibernate you would probably use SessionFactory
http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-4-spring

Comment: There have been major changes from hibernate 4.x.x to hibernate 5.x.x. The newer version is inclined more towards jpa specifications. So, depending on which version you are using, your code would be quite different.

Comment: I want to use Hibernate 5